# How do I make a command call a different command along with itself?

Tags: discord, discord.py

I don't know how to do this and I have been looking for answer but am unable to find it.

```
if message.content.startswith('^trivia autostart'):
 await client.send_message(message.channel, "Game is starting!\n" + 
str(player1) + "\n" + str(player2) + "\n" + str(player3) + "\n" + 
str(player4) + "\n" + str(player5) + "\n" + str(player6) )
```

--

I have this code and i'm trying to make it so it when that code gets run that it calls my ^trivia play command without typing it in chat. 
Is this possible?

Comment: Put the actual logic in separate coroutines (`async def` functions), then you can `await` it from both places.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to that would be defining functions for each command you need to be called globally by your bot. Take the following example:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();

bot.on('error' => console.log);

bot.on('message', message => {
  let prefix = '!';
  let sender = message.author;
  let msg = message.content;
  let cont = msg.split(' ');
  let args = cont.slice(1);
  let cmd = msg.startsWith(prefix) ? cont[0].slice(prefix.length).toUpperCase() : undefined;

  // Ping function
  // can be: function pingCommand () {...}
  let pingCommand = () => {
    message.channel.send(`Pong!\nTime: ${bot.ping} ms`);
  }

  // Main command
  if (cmd === 'PING') {
    pingCommand();
  }

  // Calling command in another command
  if (cmd === 'TEST') {
    message.channel.send('Running a ping test on the bot');
    pingCommand();
  }
});

bot.login(token);
```

Hope you understand how it would work

Comment: I'm sorry, I just recognized you're using python and not JavaScript. I think it will be the same idea anyways, global functions.